# Web application session timeout using Spring security OAuth2 authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, auth0

I have a web-application on Java Spring server which serves a react client.
I use spring security OAuth2 for user authentication (using Auth0).

I want to make sure that idle sessions are logged out after 15 minutes.

I've read about some specific technical configuration options like:

- spring session timeout property
- JWT lifetime
- refresh tokens

But I didn't see any complete solution explanation.

What are the best practices to achieve this requirement?

Comment: best practice is to not hand out JWT tokens to browser clients as it was never their purpose. Having long JWT lifetimes is a MAJOR security risk and should be avoided at all costs. Only way to log out a JWT token is to manually keep track of all JWTs server side in a store/database and invalidate them server side. And by so you have basically implemented session based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you use Spring Session you can use this property `spring.session.timeout` or if not then you could use `server.servlet.session.timeout` for a servlet application.

Also paraphrasing from the docs, on that property, you set the duration suffix or if not it will use seconds.

Setting that property will timeout the session on the time that you specified on the Spring backend when the session is idle.

Comment: What about the JWT expiration? In case the JWT lifetime is long, the user will be able to log in again

Comment: Oh, that's kinda more complex then. For example I have a NextJS app that also uses Spring OAuth2 Client, but since my SPA only holds the SESSION token in the browser, when it times out it forces the SPA to login back and the JWT is never seen by anyone just by my spring backend. But yes, you have my curiosity about the token can outlive the session. What I can think of is that the JWT should be short lived, since the only way to invalidate them is the /revoke endpoint from you Auth server.